# Prove that $f\notin\text{RS}_{f}([0,1])$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

If $f(x)=\begin{cases}
         \sqrt{x}\sin{(1/x)},&\hbox{if $x\neq0$}\\
         0,&\hbox{if $x=0$}
         \end{cases}$

Prove that $f\notin\text{RS}_{f}([0,1])$.
I think this can be solved using Reduction to Riemann Integral Theorem, but I don't have any idea. Please any suggestion.

Comment: what does $\text{RS}_f([a,b])$ mean? What is $a, b$?

Comment: It means, $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes Integrable respect to $f$ in the interval. I'll change a little mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Denote $x_n = \frac{1}{n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}}$ and consider the partition

$$0 < x_{2n} < x_{2n-1} < x_{2n-2} < \dots < x_2 < x_1 < 1.$$

Then prove that

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{i=0}^{2n} f(x_{i+1})\left(f(x_{i+1}) - f(x_i)\right) 
\end{aligned}$$ diverges as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an idea to solve it.